# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager at Weblogic deployment

Tags: ldap, log4j, weblogic-10.x

When I Put ApacheDS LDAP librarians and its dependencies JARs into Weblogic shared library I am getting below exception.

I have log4j-1.2.17, slf4j-api-1.7.5 and slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5 in the classpath.

Can anybody help me out? What is wrong?

```
    Target state: deploy failed on Server AdminServer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager
    at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:72)
    at weblogic.Deployer.mainWithExceptions(Deployer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy.invokeMain(WLDeploy.java:420)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy.execute(WLDeploy.java:349)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:40)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1253)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:106)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForEach.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1369)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1253)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Task 9 failed: [Deployer:149026]deploy application sumsscheduler on AdminServer.
Target state: deploy failed on Server AdminServer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager

    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Jsr88Operation.report(Jsr88Operation.java:542)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.perform(Deployer.java:140)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.Deployer.runBody(Deployer.java:88)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
    at weblogic.Deployer.run(Deployer.java:70)
    at weblogic.Deployer.mainWithExceptions(Deployer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy.invokeMain(WLDeploy.java:419)
    at weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy.execute(WLDeploy.java:349)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForEach.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It due to the Spring framework use different version XML apis. so I have removed the following ApacheDS JARS from the classpath

- xml-apis-2.0.2
- xpp3-1.1.4c